# Listing calendar names of all active calendars

Tags: vbscript, calendar, outlook

I'm trying to list all the calendar names in Outlook (my own and shared calendars).

```
dim oApp
dim oNameSpace
dim oFolder
dim fChild
dim fParent
dim sNames

  fChild = Folder
  fParent = Folder
  sNames = ""
  set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

  for each fParent in oNameSpace.Folders
    for each fChild in fParent.Folders
      if fChild.DefaultItemType = 9 then 
        sNames = sNames & fParent.Name & " -- " & fChild.Name & vbCrLf  
      end If
    next
  next
MsgBox(sNames)
```

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tou can use the [NavigationModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.navigationmodule%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object to iterate through all the groups of folders.  Typically you could use `objNavMod.NavigationGroups.GetDefaultNavigationGroup(olPeopleFoldersGroup)`, but if the user has added groups of calendars manually then this won't get you all the calendars.  Also it's possible that permissions prevent accessing the folder programmatically; the code below allows for this.

```
const olFolderCalendar = 9
const olModuleCalendar = 1
Dim objOL 
Dim objNS 
Dim objExpCal 
Dim objNavMod 
Dim objNavGroup 
Dim objNavFolder 
Dim objFolder 
Dim colExpl 
dim s

s = ""
set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = oApp.Session
Set colExpl = oApp.Explorers
Set objExpCal = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer
Set objNavMod = objExpCal.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
For Each objNavGroup In objNavMod.NavigationGroups
    For Each objNavFolder In objNavGroup.NavigationFolders
        On Error Resume Next
        Set objFolder = objNavFolder.Folder
        If Err = 0 Then
            s = s & objNavGroup.Name & " -- " & left(objFolder.FolderPath,30) & vbcrlf
        Else
            s = s & objNavGroup.Name & " -- " & objNavFolder.DisplayName & " [no permission]" & vbcrlf
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
Next
Set oApp = Nothing
Set objNS = Nothing
Set objNavMod = Nothing
Set objNavGroup = Nothing
Set objNavFolder = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set colExpl = Nothing
msgbox s
```

In VBA:

```
Sub IterateAllCalendars()
    Dim s As String
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.namespace
    Dim objExpCal As Outlook.Explorer
    Dim objNavMod As Outlook.CalendarModule
    Dim objNavGroup As Outlook.NavigationGroup
    Dim objNavFolder As Outlook.NavigationFolder
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim colExpl As Outlook.Explorers

    s = ""
    Set objOL = Application
    Set objNS = objOL.Session
    Set colExpl = objOL.Explorers
    Set objExpCal = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer
    Set objNavMod = objExpCal.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar)
    For Each objNavGroup In objNavMod.NavigationGroups
        For Each objNavFolder In objNavGroup.NavigationFolders
            On Error Resume Next
            Set objFolder = objNavFolder.Folder
            If Err = 0 Then
                s = s & objNavGroup.Name & " -- " & Left(objFolder.FolderPath, 30) & vbCrLf
            Else
                s = s & objNavGroup.Name & " -- " & objNavFolder.DisplayName & " [no permission]" & vbCrLf
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    Next
    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    Set objNavMod = Nothing
    Set objNavGroup = Nothing
    Set objNavFolder = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set colExpl = Nothing
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: Indeed the code works now but is giving me the names of the mail folders and not the calender names :(

Comment: See my edit; I updated it to filter based on the folder default item type.

Comment: Thanks for your response Geoff, and im sorry for my late reaction. Your code looks good, only it seems to be VBA and I need it in VBScript so when I try your code the declaration part fails.

Comment: I've edited my code in the original question so you can see where I'm at right now.

Comment: Sorry! I somehow missed the vbcript tag.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Once again thanks alot for helping me Geoff, your code works perfect but only seems to return the calendar folders that are on my E-mail tab. I've got some shared calenders from people aswell but those dont seem to show up. These shared calendars are visible on the Calendar tab. Is there a way to get those aswell?

Comment: Ok, I updated again with a different method which should be much better at getting all the calendars, and should be faster to boot.  If this works, I'll delete all the pieces above it and leave the bit that works.

Comment: Yes! Thanks alot! This works, sometimes I get a guid and sometimes the name but it works!

Comment: Excellent - I'll tidy the answer up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

@Geoff: Because this was the only slim, structured and working code I found - and I searched quite a while - I add my translation to pure WSH JScript.

```
var olAppointmentItem =  1;
var olFolderCalendar  =  9;
var olFolderNotes     = 12;
var olModuleCalendar  =  1;
var olMyFoldersGroup  =  1;

var oOtlk    = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application' );
var oMAPI    = oOtlk.getNameSpace("MAPI");
var oFldCldr = oMAPI.getDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar);
var oExpl    = oFldCldr.GetExplorer;
var oNavMod  = oExpl.NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(olModuleCalendar);

var msg = "";

var eGrps = new Enumerator(oNavMod.NavigationGroups);

for (; !eGrps.atEnd(); eGrps.moveNext()) {
    var oGrp = eGrps.item();

    msg += oGrp.Name + "\n";

    var eFlds = new Enumerator(oGrp.NavigationFolders);
    for (; !eFlds.atEnd(); eFlds.moveNext()) {
        var oFld = eFlds.item();
        msg += "\t" + oFld.DisplayName + "\n";

    }

}   

WScript.echo(msg);
```